# How to get laravel_session in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, session-cookies

Is there a way to get laravel_session and show it in my Controller?

[image]

FYI, I use laravel 5.2.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using `$request->cookie('name');`?

Answer (score 3):

May be it's too late, but hope this helps someone like me. In Laravel 5.6 it working that way:

```php
function __construct(Request $request) { 

dd($request->cookie('laravel_session'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-session) method to get the session inside controller like this:

```
$session_array = session()->all();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it with var_dump(session()->all()) , but everything that show in session()->all() is different from laravel_session that I need. @SaumyaRastogi

Comment: What do you need from laravel_session ??

Comment: I need the unique value of laravel_session. You can refer on my image question. I need it to be used in cart system. @ SaumyaRastogi

Comment: You cannot get that value, as that cookie names are web browser based, which browsers keeps to track the cookies